# Angular parameter seems to have no effect in Style

Tags: angular, angular6, angular7

I have the following Angular template [StackBlitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mk-angular-progress):

```
<div class="progress">
  <div class="complete" style="width: {{progress}}%">&nbsp;</div>
</div>

<p>{{progress}}%</p>
```

The code `width: {{progress}}%` does not work but if I replace it by `width: 60%` then it does.

And the code `<p>{{progress}}%</p>` renders the correct value ...

The component code is:

```
export class ProgressComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() current: any;
  @Input() minimum: any;
  @Input() maximum: any;

  progress: number;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.progress = 100 * (this.current - this.minimum) / (this.maximum - this.minimum);
  }

}
```

Any idea what I am missing?

Comment: bind to style.width
`[style.width]="progress"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this:

```
<div class="progress">
    <div class="complete" [style.width.%]="progress">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

you can try:

```
 <div class="complete" [ngStyle]="{width: progress + '%'}">&nbsp;</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to bind inline style in your Angular 2 templates. 
Here's how you would bind a single style value for example:

```
<p [style.background-color]="'red'">
  my background is red
</p>
```

so, your updated code will be -

```
<div class="progress">
  <div class="complete" [style.width.%]="progress">&nbsp;</div>
</div>

<p>{{progress}}%</p>
```

**In addition**: 
you can also use `px`, `em` at the place of `%`.

you can set condition here.

```
<p [style.font-size.px]="isItGreaterThan60 ? '60' : '16'">
  I am some text
</p>
```

It is for single property. what will we do if we need to apply multiple styles? 
[ngStyle] is the savior.

> [ngStyle] for multiple styles

```
<p [ngStyle]="{ 'background-color': 'red', 'font-size': '30px', 'width':'60%' }">
 I am multiple styles
</p>
```

you can write css in html or you can add a property in component ts file and use it in html. like this -

```
<p [ngStyle]="myStyles">
    I am for multiple styles.
</p>
```

`'myStyles'` is a object of you component. so, In your component,

```
myStyles = {
 'background-color': 'red',
 'font-size': '30px',
 'width': '60%'
}
```

you can also use a method and return the style object. then use the method name inside html tag. like this -

```
<p [ngStyle]="getMyStyles()">
    my styles comes from a function
</p>
```